# JSONField custom error message

Tags: json, django

I'm currently reviewing an application i'm working on which use JSONField for json entries in the model like so.

```
json_config = JSONField(blank=True)
```

I noticed that if I'm editing the model in django admin and if the json is invalid, the field returns the following message

> Enter valid JSON

which is good but not entirely helpful as i sometimes don't know exactly where the error is in the JSON. For example, if i use simplejson.loads() for strings which look like json objects, it returns a message indicating approximately where the line and character is where the error occurs.

> Invalid control character u'\r' at: line 5 column 16 (char 78)

I couldn't find something similar to it for JSONField. Is there i way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: is this the postgresql jsonfield or a third party extension?

Comment: i believe it's django-jsonfield

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit late but what i did for this was, on the form itself, i used a TextField whose input i then pass to simplejson.loads() which in turn returns the error message that I need back to the form. Once everything checks out with the json and is valud, i pass the contents of the simplejson.loads() to the JSONField for saving.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to override your `clean` method of the model and check to the json there in order to return a helpful message.

If you want to edit the json only via the admin interface, I found [the django-jsoneditor](https://github.com/nnseva/django-jsoneditor) to be very helpful.

Comment: hi @Remi. i tried django-jsoneditor out but the styling came out wrong when i was checking django admin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv3uO.png

it didn't look like the one here
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a1df47e8e574e0de60ce742891524c85edd09477/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f6a6f7364656a6f6e672f6a736f6e656469746f722f6d61737465722f6d6973632f6a736f6e656469746f722e706e67

from the [django-jsoneditor](https://github.com/nnseva/django-jsoneditor). although i did configure it properly. The buttons work though but their labels are wrong